# SwiftUI ForEach Buttons making 1 large button

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to list multiple cells of button in my scrollview but when I do that it lists them out when I click on any of them it clicks all of them and looks like its just 1 big button with 4 different cells

```
        ZStack{
        Color("Background")
        VStack{
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                ForEach(userVM.user?.chats ?? [ChatModel()]){ chat in
                    Button(action:{
                        print(chat.name ?? " ")
                    },label:{
                        Text("\(chat.name ?? " ")")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `ForEach` loop, you want to make sure each `ChatModel` is unique. Usually you do this by including an id in your `ChatModel` and making it Identifiable.

So try this, if you do not have an id in `ChatModel`:

```
ForEach(userVM.user?.chats ?? [ChatModel()], id: \.self){ chat in ...}
```

or this, if `ChatModel` has an id:

```
ForEach(userVM.user?.chats ?? [ChatModel()], id: \.id){ chat in ...}
```